# «Судебная практика по этим вопросам слишком мала», т.е мало случаев. Как верно выразиться?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Судебная практика по этим вопросам слишком мала», т.е мало случаев. Как верно выразиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В судебной практике подобные случаи встречаются крайне редко.

Answer (score 0):

**Судебная практика по этим вопросам невелика.**

Пример:

Судебная практика по статье 128.1 УК РФ. http://klassikaknigi.info/blog/kursovaya-rabota-kleveta/

Вплоть по сегодняшний день судебная практика по ст. 128.1 УК РФ **относительно невелика** и не сравнится с судебной практикой по многим иным статьям Уголовного кодекса. Большинство приговоров являются оправдательными.

**Судебная практика** – юридический термин, которому можно дать количественную оценку.

Для справок:

Судебная практика – это совокупность решений судов (в первую очередь высших) по различным категориям дел, играет роль вспомогательного источника права, восполняя пробелы, существующие в законодательстве. В Российской Федерации судебная практика не порождает обязательных норм, но оказывает значительное воздействие на деятельность судебной системы, и на правовую систему в целом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно выразиться так: "Судебная практика в этой oблaсти недостаточна (недостaточнo обширна)"

Примечание: вызывает сомнение корректность выражения "судебная практика по вопросам".